# Multiple Line text string to column header XLS pattern recognition and conversion

Tags: javascript, powershell, vbscript

I have a rather large export of installed software generated by powershell.. The pattern appears as follows

[image: text pattern block]

Is there a snippet that can produce an output such that "IdentifyingNumber, Name, Vendor, Version, Caption are tab delimited column headers with all the remaining content neatly listed under it? The idea to have a neat sortable spreadsheet as opposed to the repetative block formatted text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the powershell-script you that gathers the data/objects and make it export the objects to a CSV-file, which can easily be imported to Excel or another spreadsheet-application (or database). Ex. your script today does this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product
```

What you want to do is to pipe the output from `Get-WmiObject` to `Export-CSV`. I'll also use `Select-Object` in the sample below so we can specify the order of the columns.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product |
Select-Object IdentifyingNumber, Name, Vendor, Version, Caption |
Export-Csv -Path MySoftware.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want tab as the delimiter, change the last line to:

```
Export-Csv -Path MySoftware.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t"
```

Comment: life..saver. Thanks!